# Navigation bar not showing in kitkat

Tags: java, android, user-interface

This is my code involving navigation bar.The navigation bar gets displayed easily on android versions above kitkat but no navigation bar is shown in kitkat and below versions.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Which toolbar are you using `appcompat.Toolbar` or just `Toolbar`?

Comment: i am using just Toolbar @SripadRaj

Comment: You should be using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your xml as well as declaring in your java. **Note:** you have to import [Design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to use appcompat toolbar.

Comment: after using drawer layout navigation bar shows ,but application freezes @SripadRaj

Comment: freezes with **App not responding**?? or **Unfortunately stopped**??